# Calling button event for custom dialog

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call event of button click which is in custom dialog. Here is my custom dialog code

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
        case MY_DIALOG:
            dialog= getInstanceMyDialog();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}

private Dialog getInstanceMyDialog() {
    final Dialog bookMarkDialog= new Dialog(this,R.style.BookmarkDialogNoTitle);
    bookMarkDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bookmark_dialog);
    return bookMarkDialog;
}
```

There are two buttons in my dialog Add and Cancel.
I don't know where to fire the event of button click.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Dialog getInstanceMyDialog() {
  final Dialog bookMarkDialog= new Dialog(this,R.style.BookmarkDialogNoTitle);
  bookMarkDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bookmark_dialog);

  Button addButton = (Button)bookMarkDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogAddButton);
  addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClick .........)
  ......... same for cancel.

  return bookMarkDialog;
}
```

Didn't test it but should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the view and set the listener for the buttons.

```
private Dialog getInstanceMyDialog() {
    final Dialog bookMarkDialog= new Dialog(this,R.style.BookmarkDialogNoTitle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_dialog, root);
    /// set the listener for your buttons.
    Button button1 = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    bookMarkDialog.setContentView(contentView);
    return bookMarkDialog;
}
```

Comment: this one will also work but I think we need setOnClickListener for button instead of setOnItemClickListener :)

Comment: can you tell me what to pass as root in inflater ?

Comment: You can use inflate(resource, null, false). Last parameter is needed because when second is null this will not work. Your layout in this case doesn't have any parent layout so null should be fine.